# AngularJS routing - call function based on matching URL host name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AnguarJS, I would like to call a function anytime a specific host name exist in a link clicked within the current web site. The user would continue on to the link clicked but the function would be called in the background.

Is $routeProvider the best direction to head for something like this?  It would need to be site wide so that is why I was thinking the AngularJS routeProvider might work.  I'm asking first because I am new to Angular.  I am trying to avoid having to identify each click event to listen for this specific domain name in a link is that there are so many places and they change because a CMS is being used.

Thank you!!

Comment: `$routeProvider` only works for "internal" application routes (`/#/foo`). You probably need to listen for click events on those external links.

Comment: Thanks Sergui!  
The reason I am trying to avoid having to identify each click event to listen for this specific domain name in a link is that there are so many places and they change because a CMS is being used. This is why I was hoping to use $routeProvider  .when  to try and  match the host name then call a function if it matches.  I don't need to redirect, just to call a function if a link is clicked with "adomainname.com" for instance.

Doesn't routeprovider "see" each link click on a site given that you can check it for path and parameter strings?  

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `$routeProvider` you can only define routes on the same domain and in the AngularJS context only. That's implicit. So you can only "capture" URL segments *after* the `#` sign (hashbang).

As I said, you'll probably need to do this:

```
$(body).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    // now do something with url 
});
```

I'm using jQuery for simplicity and [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for performance reasons.

Note that this *won't* work if links change the URL of the current page. That means you are navigating to another page and destroying the current one, the one where this JS code is running and listening for `click` events. This can only work if for example you are using `target="_blank"` on the links.

A way to make it work for external and `target="_self"` links:

```
$(body).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    if(url === 'http://example.com/') {
         e.preventDefault(); 
         // 1. do some stuff, even AJAX
         // 2. after stuff completes:
         window.location = url;
    }
});
```

This unfortunately means the user has to wait for whatever happens at (1) before he's actually taken to the new URL. Maybe hiding everything visible on the page together with `e.preventDefault` is enough if whatever you are doing is fast (less than one second).

Comment: Ah OK, that makes perfect sense that it only captures the path and params.  The click events will change the URL of the current page so this may not work.  

Pseudo: When on domain1 and a request is made to go to domain2, call a function then go to domain2 in same window.

BTW: The function that will be called will simply record some analytics info before domain2 is loaded. This analytics package will not capture that automagically for us, unfortunately it has to be told.

Comment: See my updated answer for a way of handling this case. It uses `event.preventDefault` and `window.location`.